# javafx: how to handle items(textfields, labels, etc)?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

i used scene builder to generate a layout, after exporting the fxml i imported into TextPad, the layout was sucessefuly imported however i cant handle the items by the id(if thats how it works). my question is how do handle the items that i added.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class test2fx extends Application{


        public static void main(String[] args){

            Application.launch(args);
        }
        public void init(){
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxlayout.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();

        }
        public void stop(){
            System.exit(0);
    }
```

fxml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="284.0" prefWidth="314.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="31.0" layoutY="252.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Jogar" />
      <Button layoutX="124.0" layoutY="252.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Novo" />
      <Button layoutX="219.0" layoutY="252.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Sair" />
      <TextField id="tf1" disable="true" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="60.0" />
      <TextField id="tf1" disable="true" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="100.0" />
      <TextField id="tf3" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="140.0" />
      <TextField id="tf4" disable="true" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="180.0" />
      <Label id="lb1" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="59.0" text="Inicio" />
      <Label id="lb2" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="59.0" text="Fim" />
      <Label id="lb3" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="139.0" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="59.0" text="Palpite" />
      <Label id="lb4" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="180.0" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="59.0" text="Inicio" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: Use `fx:id` and a [Controller class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers)

Comment: When you add id in the fxml and you use SceneBuilder go up to the menubar click on (View)  menu and then on (View Sample Controller) copy the code and past it on your java controller class.Very usefull when using fx:id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @James_D said you most likely want:

1. A reference to the element in your FXMl you wish to access.
2. A controller class for your FXML.

Example:

```
/*
 * Dean2191 Stackoverflow example
 */
package javafxapplication6;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author dean2191
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private TextField tf1; // value will be injected by the FXMLLoader

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

Check the oracle examples [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to) and also note that the netbeans IDE generates a default controller class as shown above however when a new element is added in scene builder you should add each @FXML annotation to the variable you wish to access and scene builder/netbeans have synchronization features to view which elements are referenced from your code.

> Synchronizing With the Controller Source Code The NetBeans IDE's Make
>   Controller feature allows you to synchronize the modifications you
>   make in the FXML file that is currently opened in Scene Builder and
>   the controller source code opened in NetBeans IDE. To illustrate this
>   feature, do the following:
>
> In Scene Builder, drag a Button control from the Library panel to the
>   Control panel. In the Code panel, assign a new value for the new
>   button's fx:id field and a new method name for the onAction method.
>   Select File in the main menu and then Save. In NetBeans IDE 7.4 or
>   later, right click the project node for the FXML file that you just
>   edited and select Edit from the contextual menu. From the main menu,
>   select Source and then Make Controller. The @FXML private variable and
>   the new onAction method for the button you just added in Scene Builder
>   are created in the controller source file. Use the Make Controller
>   command if you delete an element in the Control panel or update an
>   fx:id value or a method name in Scene Builder.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/sb-with-nb.htm)

Also note you should check in your FXMl for this line:

```
fx:controller="yourNamespace.fxlayout"
```

As your controller class must be specified somewhere in the FXML. Your controller will then be called something like fxlayout.java in your example code. This can be set/modified using scene builder too:

[image]